# Installing Alpine Linux in a chroot

Tags: embedded, chroot, alpine-linux

Alpine expertise!

I am going to make Alpine chroot.
So I am following

```
http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_Linux_in_a_chroot
```

I unpacked

```
unzip apk-tools-static-*.apk
```

But I can't find sbin/apk.static

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`apk`s are gzipped tarballs. Therefore you should unpack it like this:

```
tar zxf apk-tools-static-*.apk
```